# Specifying integration level of time series

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, models, cointegration, testing

Following model was estimated on 200 observations. How to specify the level of integration of $X_t?$ In brackets there are standard errors and p-value of Breusch-Godfrey test is also shown.

$X_t=0,02+\underset{(0,06)}{0,94}X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t\qquad pv(BG)=0,765$

$\Delta X_t=0,03-\underset{(0,71)}{0,52}X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t\qquad pv(BG)=0,878$

$\Delta X_t=0,03-\underset{(0,05)}{0,51}X_{t-1}-\underset{(0,09)}{0,02}\Delta X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t\qquad pv(BG)=0,775$

$\Delta \Delta X_t=0,02-\underset{(0,05)}{0,62} \Delta X_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t\qquad pv(BG)=0,852$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's on [stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/168612/7469) and fits better there.